# Postgres default value NULL and empty string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Usually the default value is used if the value to insert is NULL. Is there a way to tell postgres that it should use the default value also on empty string ('')?

Comment: _Usually the default value is used if the value to insert is NULL._ No. The default value is used if no value is issued. The default value for the default value is null.

Comment: ok, I can try to use a trigger

Comment: You could instead *disallow* empty strings, using a check constraint or `DOMAIN`: `Create Domain non_empty_text As text Check ( trim(VALUE) != '' );` then use `some_column_name non_empty_text NOT NULL` as your column declaration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't do so directly.

The only valid ways to specify a default value are:

- To omit the column from an `INSERT` column-list; or
- To explicitly specify the keyword `DEFAULT` for a column in an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Neither `NULL` or `''` are valid ways to request a default value for a column.

If you wish to replace `NULL` or `''` with the default you must use a `BEFORE ... FOR EACH ROW` trigger to do so.

Making a generic one isn't especially trivial, as you can't use the `DEFAULT` keyword when assigning to the `NEW` tuple within a trigger; you'd instead have to look up the system catalogs for the default expression.

Of course, you can always just repeat the default expression in the trigger if you know it and don't mind coding a trigger specific to it.

All in all, it's way better to fix the application so it follows the standard and doesn't expect the DB to replace `NULL` or `''` with a default value.